# Error while self indexing in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example of what I mean which makes things clear:

```
require(data.table)
x = data.table(a=1:10, idx=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace=TRUE))
x[idx]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'idx' not found
```

However, the following works:

```
x[idx[]]
#a  idx
#1:  2 TRUE
#2:  5 TRUE
#3:  7 TRUE
#4:  9 TRUE
#5: 10 TRUE
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Interesting: `x[idx == TRUE]` also works. So does `x[(idx)]`.

Comment: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.datatable/1588/focus=1589

Comment: got it. i'll leave this question up in case others find it useful but feel free to close.

Comment: you can paste that link into an answer and i'll accept also.

Comment: Whoever does it should paste in contents of the linked post.

Comment: This is the documented behavior. perhaps you might want to change the name of question?       Incidentally, another option is to use `x[c(idx)]`

Comment: @DavidRobinson, that's because in `x[(idx)]`, the `(idx)` is evaluated as an expression (within the data.table environment) and therefore the values of `idx` are obtained. Whereas `x[idx]` looks for `idx` variable in it's (and parent) environment and returns empty-handed. A bit tricky, I find.

Comment: @Alex, would you like to write up an answer so that this question can be marked off as complete

Comment: Essentially any expresion _other than_ `x[idx]` that involves `idx` will evaluate `idx` within the scope of the `data.table`.

Comment: @Alex, you should paste the contents of the link yourself and accept it as an answer so that the question remains answered/closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the link provided in the comments by @GSee.

> > Hi,
> >     Yes expected. From ?data.table:
> >     "Advanced: When i is a single variable name, it is not considered an 
> >     expression of column names and is instead evaluated in calling scope."
> >     Subsetting by a logical column is the only example I can think of where 
> >     this is confusing. But we make use of this feature quite a lot e.g.
> >          TMP=list(...);DT[TMP]
> >     safe in the knowledge that DT[TMP] won't start to fail if DT in future 
> >     has a column called TMP.
> >     When I have a logical column boolCol I wrap with ():   DT[(boolCol)].
> >     This avoids the memory allocation and scan of ==TRUE,  and avoids the 
> >     variable name repetition of DT[DT$boolCol]
> >     Matthew